# How to define the loss function or how to optimize if the target is a set?

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I use a full-connected network to get the whole words distribution from the last state of an encoder.

For example, there are 5 words in the vocabulary.

```
P = [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0,4]
```

And the ground truth is a words' set for this train data.

I sample 3 words from the 5 words and if the target set contains the 3 words , then I want the probability of the 3 words in `P` increase, for this state.

If one of the 3 word is not in the target set, then I want the probability of the word in `P` decrease, for this state.

So I wrote these code:

```
reward = [0,0,0]
```

Suppose the first 3 words are sampled from `P`, and only the first 2 of the 3 words are in the target set. And the third word is not in the target set. Then

```
reward = [1,1,-1]
```

Then I compute the negative sum and dot product of `reward` and sampled 3 `P2=[0.1, 0.1, 0.2]` as the loss

```
loss = -sum(reward * P2.log())
```

But I fail to get the result: The top probability words can be selected from the vocabulary for every state.

Comment: Why do you think this is reinforcement learning? There are likelihood functions you could use for target sets that are differentiable. Unfortunately, they're not very common and the papers discussing them are a little technical, but you could look at: [Deep Sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.06114v2) or [Probabilistic n-Choose-k Models for Classification and Ranking](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/4702-probabilistic-n-choose-k-models-for-classification-and-ranking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer from [SQLNet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04436)'s equation:

[image: -]